# Dotnet Core Docker Container Leaks RAM on Linux and causes OOM

Tags: c#, linux, docker, ubuntu, .net-core

I am running Dotnet Core 2.2 in a Linux container in Docker.

I've tried many different configuration/environment options - but I keep coming back to the same problem of running out of memory ('docker events' reports an OOM).

In production I'm hosting on Ubuntu. For Development, I'm using a Linux container (MobyLinux) on Docker in Windows.

I've gone back to running the Web API template project, rather than my actual app. I am literally returning a string and doing nothing else. If I call it about 1,000 times from curl, the container will die. The garbage collector does not appear to be working at all.

Tried setting the following environment variables in the docker-compose:

```
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=true
ASPNETCORE_preventHostingStartup=true
```

Also tried the following in the docker-compose:

```
mem_reservation: 128m
mem_limit: 256m
memswap_limit: 256m
```

(these only make it die faster)

Tried setting the following to true or false, no difference:

```
ServerGarbageCollection
```

I have tried instead running as a Windows container, this doesn't OOM - but it does not seem to respect the memory limits either.

I have already ruled out use of HttpClient and EF Core - as I'm not even using them in my example. I have read a bit about listening on port 443 as a problem - as I can leave the container running idle all day long, if I check at the end of the day - it's used up some more memory (not a massive amount, but it grows).

Example of what's in my API:

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
return "You said: " + id;
}
```

Calling with Curl example:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:44329/api/values/7" -H  "accept: text/plain" --insecure
```

(repeated 1,000 or so times)

Expected: RAM usage to remain low for a very primitive request

Actual: RAM usage continues to grow until failure

Full Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication1
    mem_reservation: 128m
    mem_limit: 256m
    memswap_limit: 256m
    cpu_percent: 25
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication1/Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44329
      - DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
      - DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=true
      - ASPNETCORE_preventHostingStartup=true
    ports:
      - "50996:80"
      - "44329:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

I'm running Docker CE Engine 18.0.9.1 on Windows and 18.06.1 on Ubuntu. To confirm - I have also tried in Dotnet Core 2.1.

I've also given it a try in IIS Express - the process gets to around 55MB, that's literally spamming it with multiple threads, etc.

When they're all done, it goes down to around 29-35MB.

Comment: More data should be collected, because concluding on what's the cause, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/diagnostic-tools?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I've tried to repro but don't see the issue. Can you provide detailed repro steps including Dockerfile, compose file, and other commands? For my steps, I used the default Dockerfile from VS for a Web API project. After building, I ran `docker run --name test --memory-reservation 128m -m 256m --memory-swap 256m -p 8000:80 webapp`. Then I ran my loop from the command prompt: `for /L %G in (1, 1, 1000) do (curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/values/7" -H  "accept: text/plain" --insecure)`.  I ran that loop several times and the container never died.

Comment: I will add my Dockerfile and compose files to the original post. Thank you!

Comment: I am using https in my example, but I did try http and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: You're seeing this on both your Ubuntu production environment and your Windows host development environment?

Comment: Yes that's right. The only subtle difference is my development container doesn't get killed, it only OOMs (though it stops responding, so it's pretty useless) and the debugger obviously detaches too.

Comment: I've also tried limiting the number of cores in my compose file with: cpus: 0.5 Sadly no difference.

Comment: One thing that has made the problem go away - downgrading to dotnet 2.0 - but sadly it's EOL already

Comment: Had the same issue adding more memory helped in my case, but I think they did some work on 3.0 to fix this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0 so maybe try updating.

Comment: Did you try to use some 3rd party app in your environment? Like anything from the official samples [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-samples/) and see if you can curl it to death?

Comment: What is in your `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Note that for Docker Desktop under Windows 10, the virtual machine actually running your docker image is allocated only 2GB ram by default.  If your application needs more than that, you need to give the instance more memory.

Comment: Are you sure that the leak is related to Docker VM? Have you tried to run your Api under other host (IIS, other) to see if the leak occurs also in those conditions? Do you have any code in the middleware that could leak?

Comment: does your docker image also print logs?

Comment: Long time ago I had something similar. Even without Docker.
This command helped me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build-server

Comment: Are you using IMemoryCache?

Comment: Although you are using .net 2.2, you may want to take a look at this article which is for .net aspnet core 3.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1). A particular recommendation is that might be relevant is -- 
GC using Docker and small containers
When multiple containerized apps are running on one machine, Workstation GC might be more preformant than Server GC. For more information, see Running with Server GC in a Small Container and Running with Server GC in a Small Container Scenario Part 1 – Hard Limit for the GC Heap.

Comment: Does that behaviour persist with .NET Core 3.1? There were some changes on how the GC respects container limits which might help. (and is still supported which 2.2 is no longer)

Comment: Had a similar issue caused by a scenario in which I wasn't calling Dispose() on an IDisposable object.  At the time I was surprised at how quickly I ran out of memory (disproportionate I felt, to the resources allocated and the number of objects hanging around waiting to be garbage collected) but I was just happy to have solved my problem so can't offer further details.  **Suggestion**: try slowing your call rate down and seeing whether the problem goes away or you get more calls through before OOM (not a solution but could narrow down the search by pointing a finger at GC).

Comment: There are a number of reasons that memory can be leaked:
1. Creating more and more objects
2. Not dereferencing. Such as removing an event or delegate call to a dead object. This causes it to remain in memory for ever.
3. Calling resources that need to be disposed of manually such as files etc.

Often this is a very difficult process, especially with events. It is also a good idea to place elements in try, finally clauses to ensure that even if an exception occurs the memory is released.

Comment: does this controller has a constructor? Are you injecting something via DI ?

Answer (score 2):

This could be because garbage collection (GC) is not executed.

Looking at this open issue it looks very similar:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/851

One solution that made `Ubuntu 18.04.4` work on a virtualized machine was using  Workstation garbage collection (GC):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/851#issuecomment-644648315

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/851#issuecomment-438474207

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc

This is another finding:

> After further investigations I've noticed that there is big difference
> between my servers in amount of available logical CPUs count (80 vs
> 16). After some googling I came across this topic [dotnet/runtime#622](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/622)
> that leads me to an experiments with CPU/GC/Threads settings.
>
> I was using [--cpus constraint](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) in stack file; explicitly set
> [System.GC.Concurrent=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#systemgcconcurrentcomplus_gcconcurrent), [System.GC.HeapCount=8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#systemgcheapcountcomplus_gcheapcount),
> [System.GC.NoAffinitize=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#systemgcnoaffinitizecomplus_gcnoaffinitize), [System.Threading.ThreadPool.MaxThreads=16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/threading#maximum-threads)
> in `runtimeconfig.template.json` file; update image to a [3.1.301-bionic
> sdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk) and [3.1.5-bionic asp.net runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/) — I made all this things in a
> various combinations and all of this had no effect. Application just
> hangs until gets OOMKilled.
>
> The only thing that make it work with Server GC is `--cpuset-cpus`
> constraint. Of course, explicit setting of available processors is not
> an option for a docker swarm mode. But I was experimenting with
> available cpus to find any regularity. And here I got a few
> interesting facts.
>
> What is interesting, previously I have mirgated 3 other backend
> services to a new servers cluster and they all go well with a default
> settings. Their memory limit is set to `600 Mb` but in fact they need
> about `400 Mb` to run. Things go wrong only with memory-consuming
> applications (I have two of those), it requires `3 Gb` to build
> in-memory structures and runs with a `6 Gb` constraint.
>
> It keeps working in any range between `[1, 35]` available cpus and gets
> hanging when cpus count is `36`.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/851#issuecomment-645237830